# What's mean of the "T(C)"? when I query xml in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

What's mean of the "T(C)"?

```
DECLARE @xml XML ='<root><id>1</id><id>2</id><id>3</id><id>4</id></root>'

SELECT
T.C.value('(text())[1]','varchar(20)')
FROM @xml.nodes('/root/id') AS T(C)
```

Note:can you give me a perfessional url,I want to see carefully.

thx very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188282.aspx) `Nodes()` Function syntax is

> nodes (XQuery) as Table(Column)

*Table(Column)*
      Is the table name and the column name for the resulting rowset.